# Unable to get authentication to work using BSD sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, authentication, bsd

pretty new here. Hopefully you guys can help me out :<

I'm having issues with authenticating a user. The end goal is to have the following:

1) Client connects to server

2) Server sends username request to client, client replies with username

3) Server send password request to client, client replies with password

4) Server checks this against something (at the moment just a test comparison so "if username == test, password == test"

5) This sends a value to the client (like 1, for logged in, 0 for logged in) if 1 for logged in, client then exits the while loop and executes the rest of the code, or else if 0 then the client loops again until the user quits the program, or enters a correct username/password.

In the end the program will read in usernames/passwords from a text file that looks like

user,pass / user1,pass1 - in which case the server will just compare against all the lines and the passwords, but thats another problem later down the track.

Right now my client/server asks for the username and password, you can enter them, but I can't get steps 4 & 5 working. (the 1 for logged in, 0 for incorrect username/password) I feel like I'm missing something with sockets. like clearing a socket after each time its sent?

My code is below:

server.c:

```
while (!loggedIn) {
                while (!infoEntered) {
                    // Get username and password and makesure they're correct
                    send(client, "Please enter a username:\n", 256, 0);
                    if (recv(client, username, 256, 0) > 0) {
                        // Received username, so ask for password
                        send(client, "Please enter a password:\n", 256, 0);
                        if (recv(client, password, 256, 0) > 0) {
                            // Username and password have been entered ready for checking
                            infoEntered = 1;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            printf("Could not receive password for %s", username);
                            close(client);
                        }
                    } else {
                        printf("Could not receive the username, please reconnect and try again.");
                        close(client);
                    }
                }

                // send a test message
                send(client, "hello", 256, 0);

                char test[256];
                recv(client, test, 256, 0);
                printf("Got: %s", test);

                // I need to check login here
                // Check map/hashmap of username and passwords
                // If the username is in the file, confirm password
                // If password is correct, send a signal to the client
                // Then set logged in to 1, to start the hangman game
                loggedIn = 1;
            }
```

Full server.c code: http://pastebin.com/37YiZgWu

client.c:

```
// Loop until the user logs in or closes the program
        while (!loggedIn) {
            // Get the username
            receive = recv(server, serverR, sizeof(serverR), 0);
            printf("Server: %s", serverR);
            fgets(client, 255, stdin);
            if (send(server, client, sizeof(client), 0) > 0) {
                // Sent username to server so send password now
                receive = recv(server, serverR, sizeof(serverR), 0);
                // Get the password and send it
                printf("Server: %s", serverR);
                fgets(client, 255, stdin);
                if (send(server, client, sizeof(client), 0) > 0) {
                    char loggedReply[256];
                    recv(server, loggedReply, 256, 0);
                    if (loggedReply == "hello") {
                        send(server, "got into logged reply", 256, 0);
                        loggedIn = 1;
                    } else {
                        loggedIn = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Full client code: http://pastebin.com/p5ZFGhDJ

Thanks in advanced :( I'd normally not ask for help but I've spent 2 hours trying to get it working...

Edit replied to a comment below about clarifying "the last part":

"The last part being the actual authentication part. So everything after where the server receives the username/password. Any other send/receives I do after this just simply don't work and I don't know why. I need the server to run through an if statement which will compare the username/password, and then in both cases, send a signal to the client, so a word, integer, boolean, whatever, in which case the client would be waiting for this signal (to see if its logged in), then if logged in, in breaks out of the login while loop, runs program, or else re-loop asking for username/pass again"

Comment: "but I can't get the last part working". Please describe the actual problem. "Not working" is almost never an adequate description. As a minimum describe the inputs, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Comment: One thing to note, for STREAM sockets each `recv` is not guaranteed to receive a single message sent by the other side each time (can be more or less). Your application needs to  define a way of delimiting messages and your receiving code needs to loop on `recv` until an entire message has been received (or enough of it to proceed to the next processing step).

Comment: @AlanAu The last part being the actual authentication part. So everything after where the server receives the username/password. Any other send/receives I do after this just simply don't work and I don't know why. I need the server to run through an if statement which will compare the username/password, and then in both cases, send a signal to the client, so a word, integer, boolean, whatever, in which case the client would be waiting for this signal (to see if its logged in), then if logged in, in breaks out of the login while loop, runs program, or else re-loop asking for username/pass again

Comment: `send(client, "some string", 256, 0);` will send a lot of garbage that has to be read at the other end.  It also invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "simply don't work" does not tell us what the behaviour is. Does the `send`return an error? Does it crash? Does it block? Does the receiver get wrong data? Do aliens land and chew up your program? :-)

Comment: I said that because the I don't really know how to describe the behaviour. The exact code above, client connects, server acknowledges that. The server asks for a username, AND password. Nothing after that. Server does nothing, doesn't send any further information, Client does nothing. Nothing is printed, they're just 0 character lines as if it's an empty text file. So something to do with the way I'm trying to send the logged in status, isn't working.

Comment: As Andrew Henle has pointed out, fix all your `send` calls. The `len` parameter must be the **exact** size of the data buffer being sent. You can't just put `256` every time. That will cause the `send` to read 256 bytes. Since your string is not 256 bytes it will end up reading incorrect memory and result in Undefined Behaviour. If that doesn't help then run your program in a debugger and find out exactly where the server and client are blocked on.

Comment: So how can I go about getting the size of the string before the len parameter? or should I store each one in a separate char array? Edit: also wouldn't a char array be initialised to [256]?

Comment: `#define USERNAME_PROMPT "Please enter a username:\n"` then `send(client, USERNAME_PROMPT, strlen(USERNAME_PROMPT)+1, 0);`. And I don't know what you mean by the second question. What char array? There is no rule that says any array has to be 256 bytes.

Comment: Yeah right, sorry. I understand now. I'll fix it all up and see how I go, thanks alot!

Comment: Using a pre-defined string is giving me errors. ',' or ')' expected at the second comma, 2nd bracket, and last bracket. All the same error:

send(client, USERNAME_PROMPT, strlen(USERNAME_PROMPT)+1, 0);

Is the exact code

Comment: Do not #define your strings, unless you have to. Use const char* const variables. Also, update your code to show your last efforts, and provide full compiler error messages along the lines for which they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

there is a library for authentication: GSASL

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/manual/gsasl.html#Example-1

else i do not understand the error in detail. maybe you should use the common *session mechanism* that is also implemented in GSASL

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: this do not actually resolve the problem posted, but it is a very useful information.

Answer (score 0):

the c function fgets() incorporate newline "\n" character as a valid input. thus you are sending "username"+"\n" "password"+"\n" to server.
cleanup the string before sendint it to server.